# Run UPDATE mySQL Query on Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a table like this

librarylog

| patronName | bookId | dueDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 24 | 2024-01-14 |
| Sam | 42 | 2024-01-07 |
| Bob | 13 | 2024-01-07 |

I'm trying to create a SQL query which updates all the dueDate values and increases them by a week.

This is what I had:

```
UPDATE librarylog SET dueDate = DATE_ADD((SELECT * FROM (SELECT dueDate FROM librarylog)tblTmp), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

But this returns

`#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHS of the update should just be the `dueDate` column wrapped in `DATE_ADD`:

```sql
UPDATE librarylog
SET dueDate = DATE_ADD(dueDate, INTERVAL 1 WEEK);  -- update all records
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using MySQL syntax for your SQL query. However, the subquery you are using is returning multiple rows, which is causing an error. You should use a single value for the `DATE_ADD` function.

Here's a corrected version of your query:

```
UPDATE librarylog SET dueDate = DATE_ADD(dueDate, INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

This query directly updates the dueDate column by adding one week to the existing values. No need for a subquery in this case.